# If $abc=1$ and $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, prove that ${1 \over a+b+1} + {1 \over b+c+1} + {1 \over c+a+1} \le 1$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

> If $abc=1$ and $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, prove that $${1 \over a+b+1} + {1 \over b+c+1} + {1 \over c+a+1} \le 1\,.$$

The whole problem is in the title. If you wanna hear what I've tried, well, I've tried multiplying both sides by 3 and then using the homogenic mean.  $${3 \over a+b+1} \le \sqrt[3]{{1\over ab}} = \sqrt[3]{c}$$ By adding the inequalities I get $$ {3 \over a+b+1} + {3 \over b+c+1} + {3 \over c+a+1} \le \sqrt[3]a + \sqrt[3]b + \sqrt[3]c$$ And then if I proof that that is less or equal to 3, then I've solved the problem. But the thing is, it's not less or equal to 3 (obviously, because you can think of a situation like $a=354$, $b={1\over 354}$ and $c=1$. Then the sum is a lot bigger than 3).

So everything that I try doesn't work. I'd like to get some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Since others have already posted their successful solutions, I need  not have it repeated. I just want to point out that your homogenic mean approach will not get you anywhere. This is because if you plug in your suggested samples, you will find $\dfrac {3} {356} less-than-or-equal-to 1$. This means the comparison is NOT fair. That is, either LHS is too small or hte RHS is too large. Hence, you need to find something smaller for your RHS.

Comment: Also many answers on AoPS, you can find them with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%20%2B%20a%20%2B%20b%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%20%2B%20b%20%2B%20c%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%20%2B%20c%20%2B%20a%7D%20%5Cleq%201%24)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

let $$a=x^3,b=y^3,c=z^3\Longrightarrow xyz=1$$
since
$$y^3+z^3\ge y^2z+yz^2$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{1+b+c}=\dfrac{xyz}{xyz+y^3+z^3}\le\dfrac{xyz}{xyz+y^2z+yz^2}=\dfrac{x}{x+y+z}$$
so
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{1+b+c}\le\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{x}{x+y+z}=1$$

Comment: Where does the inequality $y^3+z^3 \geq y^2 z + y z^2$ come from?

Comment: @Aaron: $y^3+z^3-y^2z-yz^2=(y^2-z^2)(y-z)=(y+z)(y-z)^2 \geq 0$

Comment: @Aaron It is also enough to assume (WLOG) that $y\ge z$ and then to use the rearrangement inequality.

Answer (score 4):

This answer only assumes that $abc\geq 1$.  Make the following substitution $$\sqrt[3]{a}=x,\sqrt[3]{b}=y,\sqrt[3]{c}=z$$ then we have $xyz\geq1$ and we have to prove the following inequality now

$$\frac{1}{1+x^3+y^3}+\frac{1}{1+y^3+z^3}+\frac{1}{1+z^3+x^3} \leq 1 $$

Clearly $$(x^3+y^3)=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)\overset{\text{AM-GM}}{\geq}(x+y)xy$$

We have the following chain of inequalities

$$\frac{1}{1+x^3+y^3}+\frac{1}{1+y^3+z^3}+\frac{1}{1+z^3+x^3} \leq \frac{1}{1+xy(x+y)}+\frac{1}{1+xz(x+z)}+\frac{1}{1+yz(z+y)} \\ \leq \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}(x+y)}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{y}(x+z)}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}(z+y)}=1$$

Comment: +1 , nice proof . This is more easy to understand than the other one :) .

Comment: Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

For my earlier comment: By expanding everything I mean, you can clear the denominator, write down everything in terms of symmetric polynomials, and try to use AM-GM to compare them.

On the other hand, there is also a one liner, similar to math110's solution:

$$\frac{1}{a+b+1} \leq \frac{2c+ab}{2(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca}$$

After clearing the denominator, this is equivalent to $(c-1)^2(a+b) \ge 0$.

Comment: It's very nice +1.

Comment: Do you mean that I should multiply both sides by $(a+b+1)(b+c+1)(c+a+1)$? I then get that $$a^2b + ab^2 + a^2c + ac^2 + b^2c + bc^2- 2a  - 2b - 2c \ge 0.$$ But I can't see how I could continue.

Comment: @mathh, if you know Muirhead's inequality, at the final step you just homogenize your inequality (i.e. multiply $(abc)^{2/3}$ to $a+b+c$ part) and use Muirhead. If not, then try to find a clever AM-GM: for example: $a^2b+a^2c \ge 2a^{3/2}$ by AM-GM, then you can use Power mean or other approaches to prove $a^{3/2} + b^{3/2} + c^{3/2} \ge a+b+c$.

Comment: The Power mean inequality says that: $$\left(\frac{a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}}{3}\right)^{3/2}\ge\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$right? But how does this help us prove that: $$a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}\ge a+b+c?$$

Well, we could divide everything by 3: $$\frac{a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}}{3}\ge\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

And raise everything to the power of $\frac{3}{2}$:$$\left(\frac{a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}}{3}\right)^{3/2}\ge\left( \frac{a+b+c}{3} \right)^{3/2}$$

So we have left to prove that: $$\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^{3/2}\ge\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

Comment: We divide everything by $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$: $$\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{3}}\ge1$$

Which is equivalent to: $$a+b+c\ge3$$

But we don't know if that's true. It's not necessarily correct.

Comment: @mathh, it's true here, by AM-GM inequality, that $$a+b+c \ge 3$$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I have other nice Cauchy-Schwarz inequality solve it.

since
$$\dfrac{1}{1+a+b}=1-\dfrac{a+b}{1+a+b}$$
so the original inequality can be written
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a+b}{a+b+1}\ge2$$
use Cauchy-Schwarz inequaliy and the AM-GM inequality,we have
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a+b}{a+b+1}\ge\dfrac{(\sum\sqrt{a+b})^2}{\sum(a+b+1)}=\dfrac{2p+2\sum\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}{2p+3}\ge\dfrac{2p+2\sum(a+\sqrt{bc})}{2p+3}=\dfrac{4p+2\sum\sqrt{bc}}{2p+3}\ge 2$$
because use AM-GM inequality
$$\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{ab}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3$$
where $p=a+b+c$

Comment: How can you say that $$\sum\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}≥\sum({a+\sqrt{bc}})?$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

After full expanding we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq2(a+b+c)=2\sum_{cyc}a^{\frac{5}{3}}b^{\frac{2}{3}}c^{\frac{2}{3}},$$ which is true by Muirhead because $$(2,1,0)\succ\left(\frac{5}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$$ or by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2b\cdot a^2c}=2(a+b+c).$$

Comment: Yours is nice as well !

Answer (score 2):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\frac{1}{1+a+b}=\frac{c+2}{(c+1+1)(1+a+b)} \leqslant \frac{c+2}{(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2}.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{1}{1 + a + b} + \frac{1}{1 + b + c} + \frac{1}{1 + c + a} \leqslant \frac{a+b+c+6}{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2}.$$
But $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2 = a+b+c+2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ab}) \geqslant a+b+c+6.$$
So
$$\frac{1}{1 + a + b} + \frac{1}{1 + b + c} + \frac{1}{1 + c + a} \leqslant 1.$$